# Fade out div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am fading out the div #hero-image when my page scrolls. At the moment, the code below uses a nominal value of 1000 to ensure a slow fade, but my #hero-image div is 100% the height of the browser, so I'd like the full opacity transition from 1 to 0 to happen when the user scrolls the 100% height div out of the initial viewport.

Any help much appreciated!

```
/* Fade #hero-image on scroll */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#hero-image").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: So why not just replace `1000` with `$("#hero-image").heigth()` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the height of the element instead of the generic 1000 value.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e84enbf2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#hero-image").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / $('#hero-image').height());
    });
});
```

If I understand your comment correctly to make the fade out complete after scrolling half the height of the div just divide by 2.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e84enbf2/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#hero-image").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / ($('#hero-image').height() / 2));
    });
});
```

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck!

Comment: One last thing, how could I adjust your answer to cover 50% of the height?

Comment: Updated answer with new code and fiddle. Let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: You did :)
Thank you again

Comment: Possible Divide by Zero Exception May occur

Comment: Thats true @johnny5. You can add a 0 check above setting the css dungey. Also love your name johnny5 if its a short circuit reference.

Comment: Hello again @AtheistP3ace. How do I add the 0 check? I'm not sure I quite follow that!

Also, I have adjsuted the code you kindly supplied to include 2 css instructions, as I also want to adjust the 'bottom' setting as we scroll. This is set to 100px in the css. How can I make the below code change as I scroll (just like the opacity setting) and also return to the original 100px when scrolling back to the top (again, the opacity setting does this)?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#hero-image").css({
   opacity: 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / ($(this).height() / 1.5),
   bottom: 300
  });
 });
});

Comment: @dungey_140 give me a little. Driving to work. I'll help in a little. :)

Comment: @dungey_140 I am not sure I follow. At least for the code i have seen so far `bottom` won't do anything since the element needs to be absolutely or relatively positioned. But as far as resetting any value back to its original value you can check if `$(window).scrollTop() == 0` which means you are back at the top of the page then set anything you want.

Comment: I just need the code you supplied in your answer to effect two CSS attributes (opacity and bottom). The item is absolutely positioned so bottom does take effect. Your code resets the opacity back to 1 if you return to the top of the page, so I'd like the same to be true of the bottom setting too.

For example, from 100px to 300px when scrolling, but reverting to 100px when you return to the top.